# Jython JTable PrepareRenderer Runtime error Maximum Recursion Depth

Tags: java, swing, recursion, jython, burp

I have been working on a Burp Suite extension with the Jython Library. I am fairly new to working with Java Swing and JTables. I have been trying to debug this error for quite some time. Not sure what the issue is. I am fairly certain I am invoking the objects and methods correctly.

Here is the snippet of code in question:

```
def build_tasks_table(self):
    class TasksTable(JTable):
        def prepareRenderer(self, renderer, row, column):
            #print(type(renderer))
            print("{} , {}".format(row, column))
            component = super(TasksTable, self).prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column)
```

The error that appears when I navigate to the tab in question in the extension is:
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded (Java StackOverflowError)

The error happens on the last line, it never makes it past. It recursively calls the prepareRenderer method again and again.

Any help would be appreciated, I can provide any info needed to help debug this problem.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I was calling the super methods incorrectly.

The fix was

```
self.super__prepareRenderer(renderer, row, columns)
```

Cheers